# SMTP send multiple mail by adding multiple to vs Async method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, smtpclient

Question : I have a list of 50~100 person i need send email to, MailMessage allows me to add a list of To(MailAddressCollection) and just smtpClient.Send(mail) or the Async method ? What is the best practice for sending email to multiple recipients ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand from your question, you're currently trying to decide which of these is better?

**Adding all emails to a single MailMessage and send syncronously**

```
var mailAddressCollection = new MailAddressCollection();
mailAddressCollection.Add("someone@domain.com,someoneelse@domain.com...");
// initialize the message and smtpclient
smtpClient.Send(message);
```

This will result in a single email being sent. All recipients will be able to see who the email went to. Depending on application, it might be a breach of privacy if sending to customers. `Send` will block the calling thread.

**Adding all emails to a single MailMessage and send asyncronously**

```
var mailAddressCollection = new MailAddressCollection();
mailAddressCollection.Add("someone@domain.com,someoneelse@domain.com...");
// initialize the message and smtpclient
await smtpClient.SendMailAsync(message);
```

Same as above except `SendMailAsync` will not block the calling thread.

**Create a new MailMessage for each email address and send syncronously**

```
// emailAddresses is a collection of strings
var mailAddressCollection = new MailAddressCollection();
foreach (var emailAddress in emailAddresses)
{
    // initialize the message and smtpclient
    smtpClient.Send(message);
}
```

This will result in one email being sent for each email address. The recipients will not know who else got the same email as they will be the only address if the "To" field. Because an individual email is being sent for each email address, the time to complete the loop is proportional to the number of email addresses. E.g. if it takes 2 seconds to send 1 email, it will take 200 seconds to send 100 emails.

**Create a new MailMessage for each email address and send asyncronously**

```
// emailAddresses is a collection of strings
var mailAddressCollection = new MailAddressCollection();
foreach (var emailAddress in emailAddresses)
{
    // initialize the message and smtpclient
    await smtpClient.SendMailAsync(message);
}
```

Same as above except `SendMailAsync` will not block the calling thread.

**A note on using SmtpClient**

Microsoft do not recommend using `SmtpClient` for new development as it doesn't support modern protocols. They currently recommend using MailKit or other libraries. Personally, I haven't used `SmtpClient` in years, instead delegating all my email sending to third parties such as MailGun and SendGrid.

See https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0005.md

Comment: thank you for the detailed explanation, so the sendasync will continue to send email even if the previous mail did not send successful right ?

Comment: [`SendAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient.sendasync?view=netcore-3.1) is `void`, you should use [`SendMailAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient.sendmailasync?view=netcore-3.1) which is awaitable.

Comment: @thanhnguyen.1701 you've have to test what would happen if the mail didn't send correctly. I'm not sure what exceptions are thrown from the `SendMailAsync` method.

Comment: *"All recipients will be able to see who the email went to"* - A common way to avoid that is to put all the recipients in the BCC field rather than To.

Comment: @GabrielLuci adding recipients to the bcc field is usually a bad idea. Email servers will usually classify these email messages as spam. I tried it a couple of months ago. Most (if not all) recipeints never recieved the email. Lots of bounces.

Comment: @KevinBrydon Fair enough

Answer (score 2):

Rather than serialise the email sending, you can dispatch the send requests in parallel then wait for them all to finish sending.

```
IEnumerable<MailMessage> emails = // create your email collection
var sendTasks = emails.Select(smtpClient.SendMailAsync);
await Task.WhenAll(sendTasks);
```

This will be more efficient when there is a large number of emails to send.